# ASP.NET MVC Bad Practices: Controller Action Not Restricted to POST - False Alarm?

Tags: c#, fortify

I was working on some source code with Fortify on Demand, and get a few of these pop ups (C# project):

**ASP.NET MVC Bad Practices: Controller Action Not Restricted to POST**

```
 Code Flagged: public JsonResult NamesList(GetNamesForGroupsRequest request)
```

Above the noted line of code was a [HttpGet], not a POST.

methinks this is a false positive, again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest it probably is a false positive if you aren't modifying the data. The Fortify explanation for that states (my emphasis)

> ASP.NET MVC controller actions that **modify data by writing, updating,
>   or deleting** could benefit from being restricted to accept the POST
>   verb. This increases the difficulty of cross-site request forgery
>   because accidental clicking of links will not cause the action to
>   execute.

From your method signature, it looks like you are returning data based on the request rather than modifying it, so I think in your case, it could be considered a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing magical about the POST verb to prevent CSRF vs. PUT or DELETE.
If you have a good CSRF strategy in place, the specific verb used should not matter (other than GET. Do not use GET to modify data.)

Passing data via the message body and not the URL may help keep sensitive data out of logs and other places. (Assuming you are using TLS.)